# Formula to calculate chance (probability) of a dice side based on its value

Tags: math, formula, probability, dice

So I am making a simple Dice that has 6 sides, but I want to modify the chances of those 6 sides.

Now my dice can have `N` sides, it grows, so you start with 6 sided dice and you may get up to 10 sided dice. The chances for a specific side to come up on a roll depends on its value. Chances should decrease depending on the value on a side so if side value is `1` its chance is **higher** than the side numbered `6` whose chance would be much lower.

Example (6 Sided):

```
Side   :   Chance
 1     :   35  %
 2     :   25  %
 3     :   20  %
 4     :   11  %
 5     :   6.5 %
 6     :   2.5 %
```

So as sides increase the chances should decrease never going over **100**.

I tried making formula depend on the side and divide the current chance by number of sides but did not work.

**Edit:**

**Side 6** should have **6 times** less probability than **side 1** and **5 times** less probability than **side 2** and **4 times** less probability than **side 3** etc...
My example does not match this because I could not come up with numbers so they would add up to 100 and qualify the conditions.

Comment: Can you quantify "much lower" - does this need to match some formula or other? There is a large number of possible answers. You just need to assign a weight value to each possible result, then divide by the total of all weights to get individual probabilities. But there are zillions of ways to assign the weights whilst making them be progressively smaller.

Comment: @NeilSlater by "much lower" I mean for example side `6` should have `6` times less probability `than side 1` and `5` times less probability than `side 2` etc...

Comment: @GGio Your example doesn't match this condition. `Side six` has a `2.5%` chance, so `side 1` should have `15%`? Or do you need a formula to determine each chance and the numbers are just fillers?

Comment: @KevinL yes my example sucks when I tried to apply that to example I got stuck because they did not add up to 100.

Comment: @GGio: so weights of `6,5,4,3,2,1` should be just fine? Unless you also want 5 to follow some similar rule. Are your rules self-consistent?

Comment: @NeilSlater how does that translate into percent where maximum is `100`?

Comment: I want to say that you've defined mathematically conflicting conditions. Side 6 needs 2x less than side 5, and 3x less than side 4, but side 5 needs 2x less than side 4, when it can only be 1.5x. Unless you mean everything relative to side 6?

Comment: your weights are inconsistent: $w_6=w_1/6=w_2/5$ contradicts the implied $w_2=w_1/2$

Comment: @GGio: Add up 6,5,4,3,2,1 == 21. Then percentage of e.g. 1 is `100 * 6 / 21`

Comment: @KevinL any formula that can give me a solution to get a much lower percentage on higher numbered sides is sufficient does not have to be exactly 6 times or 5 times

Comment: Should the example chances be 28.57% 23.81% 19.05% 14.29% 9.52% 4.76%?

Comment: @NeilSlater thank you, seems like your solutions is working for me. If you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: @GGio: Gerhard Powell's answer has a correct formula for working with weights (although he assigned them in reverse order to your question).

Comment: Thank for pointing out. I have added a formula to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this equation:

If the dice has N sides, the total "weight" is `(N/2)*(n+1)`.<sup>1</sup>  For 6 sides, the total "weight" is `(6/2)*(6+1) = 3*7 = 21`.

Then the math is simple

```
1 -> 6 / 21 = 0.28571428571
2 -> 5 / 21 = 0.23809523809
3 -> 4 / 21 = 0.19047619047
4 -> 3 / 21 = 0.14285714285
5 -> 2 / 21 = 0.09523809523
6 -> 1 / 21 = 0.04761904761
```

Obviously 6/21 is 6 times as big as 1/21, so that part holds up.  And the summation:

```
  0.28571428571      6/21
+ 0.23809523809     +5/21
+ 0.19047619047     +4/21
+ 0.14285714285     +3/21
+ 0.09523809523     +2/21
+ 0.04761904761     +1/21
---------------     -----
  0.99999999996     21/21
```

well, the left side is close enough to 100% anyway.  Rounding being what it is.  Right side shows that this is a rounding thing and not an error thing.

<sup>*this equation (and the variant `(N/2)*(N-1)`) are seriously handy equations.  It's a shortcut for 1+2+3+4+5+6...</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In your case you make it: Side = max sides + 1 - side nr.

You can add all the chances. Divide it by 100. Divide all the sides with that number. Then all of them add to 100.

1+2+3+4+5 = 15

15 / 100 = 0.15

1 / 0.15 = 6.65

2 / 0.15 = 13.3

3 / 0.15 = 20

4 / 0.15 = 26.667

5 / 0.15 = 33.33

If you add it up it will be 100.

This way you can add ANY numbers to a side, and it will be normalized to a sum of 100. You can also replace 100 with what number you want it to add up to.

Comment: this is a good answer but it is reverse to what I was looking for. It gives higher chance for number 5 and lower chance to number 1. should be vice versa

Comment: I have fixed the formula. Side nr = max sided + 1 - side nr. So side 1, total of six sides = 6 - 1 + 1 = 6, Side 2 = 6 - 2 + 1 = 5